# Difficulty adding controller-less view to another view

Tags: android, xml, view, appcelerator-titanium, activity-indicator

I have an activity indicator that I made in its own view so that I could then put it in each of my views' accompanying tables which are a part of the search functionality for properties in my app.

activIndic.xml

```
    <Alloy>
<ActivityIndicator id="activityIndicator" message="Loading..." indicatorColor="Alloy.CFG.design.colors.hudBlue"
    style="Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG_DARK"
    >
</ActivityIndicator>
```

states.xml

```
    <Alloy>
<Window id="winState" class="container vgroup" title="Search | States" >
    <Label text="Click a state to continue." class="searchWinHint" id="hint"></Label>
    <Require id="activityIndicator" src="activIndic" type="" ></Require>
    <TableView id="stateList" class="tableView-search">
    </TableView>
</Window>
```

states.js - searchState()

```
    function searchState(){
$.activityIndicator.show();
pullStates();
$.stateList.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    //Create global state abbreviation name
    args.stateAbbr = e.row.children[1].text;
    Alloy.createController("search_tab/counties", args).getView().open();
    });
$.winState.add($.stateList);}
```

searchState is a function which is called from an "open" event listener tied to the states window. pullStates() uses an HTTP client to fill the table with a list of states to select from. The important part to note of that function is that at the end of it's onload function `$.activityIndicator.hide()` is called so that essentially once the data is loaded the indicator goes away.

However, I'm getting an error

```
    [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [951,2005] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,2006] -In /alloy/controllers/search_tab/states.js:1,336[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,2006] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: i.activityIndicator.show is not a function
```

I don't understand why the error is occurring. I'm under the impression that if a View is added to the XML through the `<Require>` tag that the states.js controller should be able to handle that view by referencing it's id. Is there something else that I'm missing or perhaps something setup wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$.activityIndicator.show();
```

it should be

```
$.activityIndicator.activityIndicator.show();
```

the first `activityIndicator` is referring to the required controlerlessView :

```
<Require id="activityIndicator" src="activIndic" type="" ></Require>
```

and the the second `activityIndicator` is you accessing the activityIndicator defined in the file `activIndic.xml`

this is the object that has the function `show`

Comment: Oh man, of course it's that simple. Thank you so much, I'll see to changing it when I'm back in the office.

Answer (score 0):

In your **activIndic.js** expose the most important methode,

```
$.show = function(status){
    $.activityIndicator.show();
}
$.hide = function(status){
    $.activityIndicator.hide();
}
```

then, in your **states.js** you call directly `$.activityIndicator.show();` or `$.activityIndicator.hide();`

Comment: That would ve been correct if the question was about controllers, but activIndic.xml is a controllerless view.